# Memcpy and Structures

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm working to copy the following structure to a byte array to send over a named pipe.  I've found that since switching from a byte array that I had given a static definition, to a vector because my host length will be of varying lengths.

Here is the outline of my structure:

```
        USHORT version;                                 // Header Version
    USHORT type;                                    // IPVersion
    USHORT count;                                   // Number of IP addresses of remote system
    USHORT length;                                  // Header Length (1)
    BYTE SysConfigLocIP[4];
    BYTE SysConfigRemoteIP[4];
    USHORT lengthHost;
    std::vector<BYTE>HostName;
```

later, after filling the structure I copy it to a byte like so:

```
    BYTE Response[sizeof(aMsg)]
    memcpy(response, &aMsg, sizeof(aMsg))
```

I find that my array is vector is holding the correct information for the host when I inspect the container during a debug.  However, after the copy to the Response byte array, I'm finding the data that has been copied is drastically different.  Is this a valid operation, if so, what can I do correctly copy the data from my vector the BYTE array.  If not, what are other strategies I can use to dynamically size the structure to send the hostnames?  Thank you for taking the moment of time to read my question, and I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Vectors use indirection to hold their data. They don't _actually_ have magical increasing and decreasing object sizes. Research "C++ serialisation".

Comment: hi @SDERST, did you realize that you can comment, upvote (when you have 15 reputation), or even accept answers to your questions? You've asked 9 questions and got 10 answers and the site works better when there's feedback from the person who asks the question. Please see meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/165400 for more information. (When you have more reputation you will be able to downvote as well.)

Comment: You say you're writing C++, so use C++ (`std::copy`)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm working to copy the following structure to a byte array to send
>   over a named pipe.

named pipe (or other forms of inter-process or inter-processor communication) does not understand your `struct`, neither do they understand `vector`. They just operate on the concept of `byte-in-byte-out`. It is up to you, the programmer, to assign meaning to those bytes.

As suggested, please read on serialization. Try starting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization. If permitted you can use the Boost solution, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html, but I would still encourage you to understand the basics first.

As an exercise, first try transferring a `vector<int>` from sender to receiver. The number of elements in the vector must not be implicitly known by the receiver. Once you achieve that, migrating from `int` to your `struct` would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

That `memcpy` will only work for POD (plain old data) types. A vector is not POD. Instead, write code to put each byte in the buffer exactly where it needs to be. Don't rely on "magic".

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time in C++ there is no reason to use memcpy. It breaks classes. Learn about copy constructors and std::copy and use them instead.